# Mobile SEO Implementation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, seo

1)According to the HTTP specifications, URLs refer to the same document regardless of the fragment identifier (the part after the hash mark). Therefore search engines ignore the fragment identifier[image]

2)With the new schemes to make our AJAX application crawlable, when we use the #! notation the crawler knows that the link refers to additional content. The crawler transforms the URL into another (ugly) URL and requests it from your web server. The web server is supposed to respond with static HTML representing the AJAX content.

[image]

3) Tried the Mobile SEO Implementation(changing the hash(#) to hashbangs(#!)) using 
1)window.location.hash 
2)window.history.pushState(data, title, url)

Links :

1)https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32472/pros-cons-of-hash-navigation-from-seo-perspective
2)http://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate

And also tried to check the the page for crawling at Google Webmaster Tools by the options Fetch as Google and Submit to Index, but no luck yet.

As we have Only one page, I think we need to separate the pages(which are embedded in that single page).so that we can set the page titles and metas for that separated individual pages

4) For this, We have to force jQuery Mobile to update URL for AJAX pages and its handling instead of hash. Please advice any alternatives if u aware.Helping in fixing the problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: can this question not be moved to serverfault?